# Difference between PDO->query() and PDO->exec()

Tags: php, pdo

I see that there is both `PDO::query()` and `PDO::exec()`. In the page that was linked, it appears that `PDO::query()` is used for `SELECT` statements ONLY, and `PDO->exec()` is used for `UPDATE`,`INSERT`,`DELETE` statements. Why do these methods exist and when to use them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Regardless of whatever theoretical difference, neither `PDO::query()` nor `PDO::exec()` should be used anyway. These functions don't let you bind parameters to the prepared statement and should never be used.

Use `prepare()/execute()` instead, **especially** for UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE statements.

Please note that although prepared statements are widely advertised as a security measure, it is only to attract people's attention. But their **real** purpose is **proper query formatting**. This gives you security too - as a properly formatted query cannot be injected as well - just as a side effect. But again - formatting is a primary goal, just because even innocent data may cause a query error if not formatted properly.

Comment: It should also be noted that preparing a statement requires overhead, so unless you're preparing once and executing many times, preparing vs. exec  will necessarily be slower.

Comment: iirc prior to PHP8.0.0 (or was it 7.4?) trying to to an ALTER TABLE with PDO::query()/PDOStatement::prepare() would friggin crash. if you wanted to run ALTER TABLE's, you'd have to use PDO::exec(), not PDO::query(). -1

Comment: @hanshenrik care to provide some proof or all you can do is just empty blab? [Go on](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php5/bc8aa323acc9f1ce9f2d8b6b60f8c880/)  show me your "crash".

Comment: @YourCommonSense wow. i know people have maintained 5.6 since it went EOL (Microsoft did it for years, after microsoft quit 5.6 support, freexian.com now maintains it), and i don't think phpize.online use the vanilla 5.6 version, it's more likely the microsoft/freexian build, but still, wow.. in a related question, do you have any idea what's going wrong here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75710543/why-does-mysql-server-not-start-in-docker-container

Comment: @YourCommonSense okay, replicating the issue was much harder than i expected, but: it only happens up to PHP7.3 (i can not reproduce it in PHP>=7.4), and it only happens if your php is compiled with the libmysqlclient driver, it does not happen if you're compiled against the mysqlnd driver. [Here](https://gist.github.com/divinity76/c09ba2a168261e32a81d4d98dcbc335c) is a Dockerfile showing the crash though, crashing with ```#15 7.839 Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053  in Command line code:1``` - sorry didn't know the impact was so small (and fixed in 7.4)

Comment: if i could retract my downvote, i would, it seems your answer is correct as of PHP7.4 (and correct in the default configuration even in PHP<=7.3, only being incorrect with non-default <=7.3 configruations), unfortunately now i get ```You last voted on this answer yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.```

Answer (score 15):

Look at the [official docs for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

- [`PDO::exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) - "Execute an SQL statement and return the number of affected rows"
- [`PDO::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) - "Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object"

Both functions execute the query, but `exec()` only returns the number of rows affected. This is useful for an `UPDATE` query where nothing useful is returned and it is only useful to know if the proper number of rows were modified.

Answer (score 7):

I made a flow chart to try to help you determine which you should be using for any given situation:

[image]

`PDOStatement::prepare()` combined with bound variables will:

- prevent accidental syntax errors
- prevent SQL injection attacks
- make repeated queries with different values more efficient. Preparing a query sends only the query to the database server without the values. When you `execute()` the `PDOStatement` you then send only the values without the query. Executing the same query 10 times with different values will be far more efficient with prepared statements.

You should never, under any circumstances, put user input directly into a query. However, if your query does not have values and you decide to use `PDO::query()` instead of `PDO::exec()`, or if you use `PDOStatement::prepare()` instead of either of the other two, it is not a security issue, but more of an efficiency issue.

### Common objections:

*"**But what if I pull the variables from the database? If I used prepared statements to put it in the database then it's safe to put them straight into other queries WITHOUT prepared statements, right?**"*

Definitely not. Just because you used a prepared statement when inserting into a database does not sanitize it for future queries. You will need to use prepared statements again when using those values in subsequent queries.

*"**But what if I just manually hard-code a string into a query, then it's safe to put them straight into other queries WITHOUT prepared statements, right?**"*

Yes, it's safe... for now. Maybe today I'm hard-coding it. Tomorrow I pull it from the database, and after that I allow users to edit that field in the database. But will I remember to go back and update the query to use prepared statements to guarantee integrity? Probably not. Prepared statements are just good practice any time you are sending values in your query.

*"**Can I ever put values directly into a query?**"*

The only time I may put values directly into a query would be, for example, sending boolean values (`1` or `0`), an empty string, or `NULL`. In any of these cases, the value would be hard-coded right into the query, not as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of the thumb: **Use neither of them**.

`PDO::query()` executes a prepared statement without any placeholders. If you try to execute a query with placeholders, then PDO will throw an error that parameters were not bound to the query. The only reason to use this method is to have cleaner code if you have SQL without any placeholders. Under the hood, it still calls `prepare` and `execute` so there's no performance benefit.

`PDO::exec` **does not use prepared statement**. Depending on the driver, the actual invocation might differ, but MySQL driver uses the textual protocol and does not check for incoming data from the server. This means that you can't bind any data to this SQL and you can't receive any data back either. It virtually limits its usefulness to 0. The only time you might want to use it is if you want to execute static SQL that doesn't produce any result set, such as `CREATE TABLE`.

**Use `PDO::prepare()` and `execute()` whenever possible.**