# Error in PDO::exec exception handling

Tags: php, pdo, exception

I have an issue with the exception handling of PDO::exec. In the following example I have an existing PDO connection and want to execute a sql-statement. This works quite well so far, but it does not work if I hand over a faulty query. In this case I want it to process the specified exception, but the program stops with a fatal error without the exception block ever executed.
Here is the erroneous code snippet:

```
try{
   $connection->exec( $query );
} catch( PDOException $err ) {
   echo "caught\n";
   echo $err->getMessage();
}
```

This results in the error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;` and the program aborts.

I have also tried:

```
if( $connnection->exec( $query ) === false ) {
   echo "Failure\n";
} else {
   echo "Success\n";
}
```

which was unfortunately equally unsuccessful. What is the problem here? Are there perhaps any best practice examples (I haven't found any so far)?

Comment: Are you trying to use this to run a SELECT query? Try looking at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16381554/4019762) as it might help

Comment: Remove `echo $err->getMessage();`

Comment: Can you post your `$query` ?

Comment: I am not trying to run any select queries and the removing of `echo $err->getMessage();` didn't change anything as well, since the echo in the previous never got executed as well.

Comment: My query is `ALTER TABLE invoices
  MODIFY invoice_netamountDECIMAL(10,2);`. It is faulty on purpose, because i want to test the exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's namespace or xdebug to blame for this uncaught exception.

> Are there perhaps any best practice examples

Sure.
Do not use exec().
Do not wrap your queries in try-catch unless you're doing it only once, in a wrapper and going to re-throw it.

> and the program aborts.

that's **exactly** what a good program ought to do when encountered with a faulty query.

Comment: What should I then use instead of exec?  I have a PDO connection and exec seems the proper method for this very task - http://at1.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php . And for my purpose the program must not abort, because it is for an automated database update and should go on with the next query (and write a log entry) if one of the statements is faulty.