# inserting two rows instead of one MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert login data into a login table, and I'm using this code:

**login.php**

```
$verify = password_verify($password, $results['user_password']);
if($verify){
    $session->logUser($results['user_id']);
    header('Location: dashboard.php');
}else{
    //Error
}
```

And then in the **session.php** I have a session class with this:

```
public function logUser($userId){
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $userId;

    $token = $this->createToken();
    $timestamp = time() + (86400 * 14);

    $connection = new Connection;
    $db = $connection->openConnection();

    $stmt = $db->query("INSERT INTO logins (login_token, login_userId, login_expires) VALUES ('$token', '$userId', '$timestamp')");
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

This is working correctly, the token is being generated, and all the data is correct but when I check the database, it's creating two records (identical ones but with different auto_increment ID).

Why is this happening?
Thanks in advance.

***EDIT:*** I'm doing this token thing in an attemp to create persistent login, I have yet to create the cookie but first I wanted to test if the login data was being stored correctly in the database.

Comment: I swear not, I checked all the code and I really can't find the problem, will post screenshots if needed.

Comment: may be a loop, or a session no trully start, or a refresh redirection  during login.

Comment: `query()` executes the query once; `execute()` runs it again. When you fix it, look into prepared statements, and don't concat your query. It defeats the purpose of PDO.

Comment: @jh1711 actually I'm using PDO to make use of prepared statements, but in this case, the three values are safe so I don't need to prepare the query. Thanks anyway, I didn't know that `query` executes it I thought you could only execute it with `execute`;

Comment: I somehow missed the one hour old answer, sorry for the slow pony. Since your values are safe, you're obv. fine.

Comment: No problem man!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing it twice.  remove $stmt->execute();

Comment: Wow, this worked :| but how? I always use execute after query.. I've been doing it wrong all this time?

Comment: execute() is for prepared queries, which you dont actually use here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381365/difference-between-pdo-query-and-pdo-exec

Comment: Yeah I get it now, I though even if you didn't use prepared statement `query` would do nothing, that you had to use `execute` so it would work if you selected something because you would just select it twice, thanks both of you!