# Is there a difference between PDO::exec and PDO::query when using PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT = true?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There seems to be a difference between `PDO::exec` and `PDO::query` when having `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT = true`. When using `PDO::exec` connections will not be reused and in the end resulting in a "to many connections" error by MySQL as they do not seem to be closed (or reused).

See for example this small code snippet:

```
<?php

$pdo_attr = [
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
];

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql;dbname=empty", "root", "iamreallysecure", $pdo_attr);

// The following will give a to many connections error after a few browser refreshes (connection limit is set to 10)
var_dump($pdo->exec("SELECT 1"));

// While the following does NOT leave >10 connections open and continues to work
//var_dump($pdo->query("SELECT 1")->fetchAll());
```

The `exec` will leave "sleeping" MySQL queries on the system (observed with `SHOW PROCESSLIST`), while `query` does not trigger this.

Is this expected? What is the difference between exec and query in this case? Or perhaps is this a bug?

Fully working (docker) example is located at https://github.com/Mattie112/mysqltest

Comment: This is a funny answer to the reasoning behind using exec or query in the first place: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16381554/2960971

Comment: Although I do find it fascinating your results when trying between exec or query in terms of persistence. I'm unable to test your observations myself, but it certainly has my interest peaked.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of the differences between exec and query. Perhaps I should have clarified that we normally don't do it this way. This was a colleague new to PHP but I still expected this to work normally. I will reply to the answers given below with some more info.

Comment: You can inform your colleague that using persistent connections is usually not recommended, because of such issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `exec()` for `SELECT` then you are already doing something wrong. This function ([as is mentioned in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)) does not fetch results from the database. It can only be used for queries, which produce no result set and which have no variable input. If a query produces a result then you need to fetch this result from MySQL using the same connection.

A persistent connection cannot be reused if it is still in use. This could happen for many reasons, one of which is unfetched result. MySQL will keep the connection open waiting for the client to perform some actions on the result set. Once the result is fetched in its entirety from MySQL server, it can then accept new queries.

This is not only a problem with persistent connections, because unfetched result set can be a problem if you use `exec()` one after the other with normal connections too.

```
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
];
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;port=3307", "root", "", $options);

// The following will give:
// SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
var_dump($pdo->exec("SELECT 1"));
var_dump($pdo->exec("SELECT 1"));
```

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. in C:\wamp64\www\test\index.php on line 16

To answer your question from the title: Yes. There is difference between using `exec()` and `query()` when using persistent connections, but this difference is also there when not using persistent connections.

tl;dr: Do not use `exec()` for queries, which produce results. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was aware that you shouldn't use exec for queries that produce results. However as it only returns the number of rows affected (and not something to "fetch" the data from I still thought this would work. There is nothing in the docs explaining that. In this case it was a colleague new to PHP. It was literally a `SELECT 1` just to check if the database connection was still alive. But what you say makes sense, it just seems strange that this is the outcome. I didn't expected that but hey every day you'll learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

You managed to confuse **everything** here. Exec is neither related to persistent connections nor too many connections error. Obviously, it's a persistent connection itself is responsible for this error.

So just two rules of thumb to solve all your present and future problems:

- **do not** use persistent connections. There is much more harm than good
- **do not** use exec(). Always use only prepare()/execute() with parameters substitute actual variables in your query