# Why does mysql server not start in docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

I have this fairly simple docker container installing a mysql server and attempting to start it, but it refuse to start. Why? What am i doing wrong here?

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get -y full-upgrade;
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y install default-mysql-server
RUN service mysql start
RUN service mysql status
```

building with
`docker build . --progress=plain`
ends with

```
#9 [6/7] RUN service mysql start
#9 0.662  * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
#9 0.725 su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory
#9 2.965    ...done.
#9 DONE 3.1s

#10 [7/7] RUN service mysql status
#10 0.832  * MySQL is stopped.
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c service mysql status" did not complete successfully: exit code: 3
------
 > [7/7] RUN service mysql status:
#10 0.832  * MySQL is stopped.
------
Dockerfile:8
--------------------
   6 |     RUN apt-get -y install default-mysql-server
   7 |     RUN service mysql start
   8 | >>> RUN service mysql status
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c service mysql status" did not complete successfully: exit code: 3
```

edit: have also tried

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
```

and

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
```

and

```
RUN apt-get -y install mariadb-server
RUN service mariadb start
RUN service mariadb status
```

same crash in all attempts  :o

Answer (score 1):

Commands like `service` broadly just don't work in Docker.  You should avoid running `service` or `systemctl` or init scripts inside a container.

Your first complication here is that a Docker image doesn't persist running processes at all.  When you `RUN service mysql start`, as part of the cleanup for that `RUN` step, any running processes are stopped.  If you do anything to start a background process or daemon in a Dockerfile, it will not be running when the next step happens.

A Docker container runs only a single foreground process and when that process exits the container will exit too.  What you should do in this case is set the image's `CMD` to run the database service in the foreground; for example

```bash
# instead of `RUN service ...`
CMD ["mysqld_safe"]
```

Also consider using the prebuilt [`mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) over building your own.

(There are two other common problems with `service`.  You see occasional questions where people try to set `CMD service x start`, but since the `service` command returns immediately the container will exit as well.  On some setups these commands depend on a running systemd, but this isn't normally running in a container, and as a heavyweight combined system-setup tool and init it doesn't quite fit in a container environment.)

Comment: illuminating, thanks! btw ```RUN /bin/bash -c 'service mysql start; service mysql status';``` actually works, mysql server is running when `service mysql status` runs (but as you say, as soon as the RUN finishes, the server is terminated)

Comment: If `service` works at all, that's true, the background process will stay running until the end of the current `RUN` command, but it still won't be persisted in the image.  (Docker automatically inserts an `sh -c` wrapper for you, you never need to `RUN sh -c '...'`.)